# Single SQL query for getting count based of 2 condition in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dml

I have data like this

[image: Table Data]

Now I need a single query to get count of id where Info is 'Yes' and count of id which are in both 'yes' and 'no'

Single query for:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE info = 'yes'
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE info = 'yes' AND info = 'No'
```

Since

```
Id having Yes are 7 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
and Id having and Yes and No both vaules are only 3 (1,4, 6) 
it should give me id_as_yes = 7 and id_as_yes_no = 3
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Since 
Id having Yes are 7 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
and Id having and Yes and No both vaules are only 3 (1,4, 6) 
it should give me id_as_yes = 7 and id_as_yes_no = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation and window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       SUM(MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) OVER () id_as_yes,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT info) = 2 THEN 1 END) OVER () id_as_yes_no
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a6f9e0624227da2615a1c3e512e487f).
Results:

```
> id_as_yes | id_as_yes_no
> --------: | -----------:
>         7 |            3
```

Comment: This Works ! Thanks @forpas https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional aggregation.

```
Select id, 
       Count(case when info = 'y' then 1 end) as y_count,
       Count(case when info = 'y' and has_n = 1 then 1 end) as yn_count
  From (SELECT id, info,
               Max(case when info = 'no' then 1 end) over (partirion by id) as has_n
         From your_table) t
```

Comment: did not work and performing slow too on 6 million data

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a subquery.  This relies on the observation that the number of ids that are "no" only is:

```
count(distinct id) - count(distinct case when info = 'yes' then id end)
```

And similarly for the number of yeses.  So, the number that have both is the number of ids minus the number of no only minus the number of yes only:

```
select count(distinct case when info = 'yes' then id end) as num_yeses,
       (count(distinct id) -
        (count(distinct id) - count(distinct case when info = 'yes' then id end)) -
        (count(distinct id) - count(distinct case when info = 'no' then id end))
       )
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...it's definitely not efficient or elegant, but no null value aggregate warnings

[dbFiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=cbac24d3992032676186cb402693f872)

```
Select
    (select count(distinct id) from mytest where info = 'yes') as yeses
    ,(select count(distinct id) from mytest where info = 'no' and id in (select distinct id from mytest where info = 'yes' )) as [yes and no]
```